# Change logo colour on scroll

Tags: html, jquery, css

I have tried to implement the [following solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58712487/change-logo-scrolling-navbar-materialize) but have doing so seems to break my website. The logo I have for the website is the same color as the navbar background, so I am trying to switch to a black logo once the navbar shows up. However the website hangs on the spinner loader and fails to load in when the code block is active. Commenting out the code fixes this and the website behaves normally. Any ideas what I am missing here? Here is the relevant code:

```js
// Javascript
// jQuery to collapse the navbar on scroll
$(window).on('scroll load', function() {
  if ($(".navbar").offset().top > 20) {
    $(".fixed-top").addClass("top-nav-collapse");
    //$("img.logo-image").attr('src', "images/master_logo_black.svg"​);
  } else {
    $(".fixed-top").removeClass("top-nav-collapse");
    //$("img.logo-image").attr('src', "images/master_logo_gold.svg"​)
  }
});
//jQuery to change to logo colour THIS IS THE ISSUE
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).on("scroll", function () {
        if($(this).scrollTop() > 20){
            $(".logo-image img").attr("src", "images/master_logo_black.svg"​);
        } else {
            $(".logo-image img").attr("src", "images/master_logo_gold.svg"​);
        }
    })
});
```

```css
.navbar-custom {
  padding-top: 0.375rem;
  padding-bottom: 0.375rem;
  background-color: #FFBF00;
  box-shadow: 0 0.0625rem 0.375rem 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  font: 600 0.875rem/0.875rem "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

.navbar-custom .navbar-brand {
  font-size: 0;
}

.navbar-custom .navbar-brand.logo-image img {
  width: 20rem;
  height: 5rem;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.navbar-custom.top-nav-collapse {
  padding: 0.375rem 1.5rem 0.375rem 2rem;
  box-shadow: 0 0.0625rem 0.375rem 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  background-color: #FFBF00;
}

.navbar-custom.top-nav-collapse .navbar-brand.logo-image img {
  fill: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)
}
```

```html
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".fixed-top">

  <!-- Preloader -->
  <div class="spinner-wrapper">
    <div class="spinner">
      <div class="bounce1"></div>
      <div class="bounce2"></div>
      <div class="bounce3"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- end of preloader -->


  <!-- Navbar -->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark navbar-custom fixed-top">
    <!-- Text Logo - Use this if you don't have a graphic logo -->
    <!-- <a class="navbar-brand logo-text page-scroll" href="index.html">redacted</a> -->

    <!-- Image Logo -->
    <a class="navbar-brand logo-image" href="index.html"><img class="logo-image" src="images/master_logo_gold.svg" alt="alternative"></a>


    <!-- Mobile Menu Toggle Button -->
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarsExampleDefault" aria-controls="navbarsExampleDefault" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-awesome fas fa-bars"></span>
            <span class="navbar-toggler-awesome fas fa-times"></span>
        </button>
    <!-- end of mobile menu toggle button -->

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarsExampleDefault">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link page-scroll" href="#header">HOME <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link page-scroll" href="#about">ABOUT</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link page-scroll" href="#research">RESEARCH</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link page-scroll" href="#experience">EXPERIENCE</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link page scroll" href="blog.html">BLOG</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link page-scroll" href="#contact">CONTACT</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <span class="nav-item social-icons">
                <span class="fa-stack">
                    <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/redacted/">
                        <span class="hexagon"></span>
      <i class="fab fa-linkedin-in fa-stack-1x"></i>
      </a>
      </span>
      <span class="fa-stack">
                    <a href="https://github.com/redacted">
                        <span class="hexagon"></span>
      <i class="fab fa-github fa-stack-1x"></i>
      </a>
      </span>
      </span>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <!-- end of navbar -->
  <!-- end of navbar -->
```

Comment: Well, I realized that I should check the browser console to see what was happening. Turns out I had a zero-width space in the lines of code that were to replace the img src. I removed them, and now everything works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to work as shown below. Try changing the image `src` on scroll as shown in the example.

```js
// Javascript
// jQuery to collapse the navbar on scroll
const $window = $(window);

$window.on('scroll', function() {
  let scroll = $window.scrollTop();
  if (scroll > 20) {
    $(".fixed-top").addClass("top-nav-collapse");
    //$("img.logo-image").attr('src', "images/master_logo_black.svg");
  } else {
    $(".fixed-top").removeClass("top-nav-collapse");
    //$("img.logo-image").attr('src', "images/master_logo_gold.svg")
  }
});
```

```css
.navbar-custom {
  padding-top: 0.375rem;
  padding-bottom: 0.375rem;
  background-color: #FFBF00;
  box-shadow: 0 0.0625rem 0.375rem 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  font: 600 0.875rem/0.875rem "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

.fixed-top {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left :0;
  width: 100%;
}

.navbar-custom.top-nav-collapse {
  padding: 0.375rem 1.5rem 0.375rem 2rem;
  box-shadow: 0 0.0625rem 0.375rem 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  background-color: red;
}

.logo-img {
  width: 50px;
  height: 20px;
  background: red;
}

.top-nav-collapse .logo-img {
  background: green;
}

.nav-item {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: .2rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>

  <!-- Navbar -->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark navbar-custom fixed-top">
    <!-- Text Logo - Use this if you don't have a graphic logo -->
    <!-- <a class="navbar-brand logo-text page-scroll" href="index.html">redacted</a> -->

    <!-- Image Logo -->
    <a class="navbar-brand logo-image" href="index.html">
      <div class="logo-img"></div>
    </a>

    <!-- end of mobile menu toggle button -->

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarsExampleDefault">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link page-scroll" href="#header">HOME <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link page-scroll" href="#about">ABOUT</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link page-scroll" href="#research">RESEARCH</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link page-scroll" href="#experience">EXPERIENCE</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link page scroll" href="blog.html">BLOG</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link page-scroll" href="#contact">CONTACT</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <span class="nav-item social-icons">
                <span class="fa-stack">
                    <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/redacted/">
                        <span class="hexagon"></span>
      <i class="fab fa-linkedin-in fa-stack-1x"></i>
      </a>
      </span>
      <span class="fa-stack">
                    <a href="https://github.com/redacted">
                        <span class="hexagon"></span>
      <i class="fab fa-github fa-stack-1x"></i>
      </a>
      </span>
      </span>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <!-- end of navbar -->
  <!-- end of navbar -->
  <div style="height:10000px"></div>
```